# Whatsapp Click-to-Chat "Couldn't open link" Error Chrome Android/iPhone

Tags: html, google-chrome, hyperlink, whatsapp

I'm using Whatsapp Click-to-chat functionality, without a phone number. It previously worked but with the new Chrome version 76.0.3809.132, both on iOS and Android is not working anymore. On Android, it's showing a Toast with *Couldn't open link*. Tried contacting Whatsapp Support but no answer as of yet. With the latest update their own documentation example is not working, [link to docs](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/). Any suggestions or experiences?

Link example:

```html
<a target="_blank" href="https://wa.me/?text=Villa%20stone%20road%20piece%2015%20meters%20from%20the%20asphalt%20street" title="Share on WhatsApp">
```

Error picture Imgur: [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1stU.jpg)

A table with [my tested devices and versions](https://imgur.com/z7sXEjE?) on Imgur

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that chrome does not accept click to chat without a number specified. Once there's a number in the URL it works just fine.
Unfortunately I did not find a hack to get around it. Neither of this worked:
https://wa.me//?text=Hello%20World
https://wa.me/0/?text=Hello%20World
only if a proper number is specified it will open WhatsApp, but has the recipient already pre selected (the number we provide).
I tested it for a client about 2 weeks ago, when it still worked. So the last update of Chrome (from Aug 26) seems to be the problem...

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, that's pretty much what I discovered too, found a hack around it, but I'll just wait for a new Chrome update. 
For the hack: I changed the link from _wa.me_ directly to _api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=&text=<insertTextHere>&source=&data=_

Answer (score 9):

If you use `https://api.whatsapp.com/send` instead of `https://wa.me/` you don't need to specify a phone number.

e.g

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=Your%20Custom%20Text
```

Comment: Yeah this does the trick (tested on Android too). The documentation here: https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/iphone/26000030/?category=5245251 is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

The best is to use the **custom url scheme format**. Universal links do not work well with native clients

```
whatsapp://send/?phone=&text&source&data
```

It will work without phone number also.

My issue on a recent breaking-change: [Universal links stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60254713/whatapp-click-to-chat-links-do-not-work-with-osx-native-client-and-whatsapp-web)

[There was a great blog post](https://medium.com/@jeanlivino/how-to-fix-whatsapp-api-in-desktop-browsers-fc661b513dc) about the issue, however it is already outdated and proposes a php specific solution (nevertheless might gives you a good idea, how to think about the problem)

Comment: This doesnt seem to work for safari at all places. Had to use https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=Your%20Custom%20Text

Answer (score 2):

```
const text = "Hello..."

const phoneNumber = "23400000000000"


Linking.openURL(`whatsapp://send?text=${text}&phone=${phoneNumber}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

First: [**Official Whatsapp Sharing Documentation**](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/).  One of the following URLs is recommended for *WEB* use...

> https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=YourShareTextHere
>
> https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=YourShareTextHere&phone=123

And these for *MOBILE* use...

> whatsapp://send?text=YourShareTextHere
>
> whatsapp://send?text=YourShareTextHere&phone=123

If you are interested in watching a project that keeps track of these URLs, then check us out!: https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls#whatsapp

[image: Social Share URLs]

Answer (score 0):

There are many changes version to version.
The solution work for me on chrome Version 117.0.5938.152 (Official Build) (64-bit)

This worked for me:  https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=91xxxxxxxxxx

Note: change your phone number instead of x

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35130377)

Comment: Link is not the answer, it's for example. if the link is changed then can be edited easily. and do you think whatsapp will change it